# Creating dictionaries with pre-defined keys

Tags: python, dictionary

In python, is there a way to create a class that is treated like a dictionary but have the keys pre-defined when a new instance is created?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily extend any built in type. This is how you'd do it with a dict:

```
>>> class MyClass(dict):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...             self['mykey'] = 'myvalue'
...             self['mykey2'] = 'myvalue2'
...
>>> x = MyClass()
>>> x['mykey']
'myvalue'
>>> x
{'mykey2': 'myvalue2', 'mykey': 'myvalue'}
```

I wasn't able to find the Python documentation that talks about this, but the very popular book [Dive Into Python](http://diveintopython.net/index.html) (available for free online) [has a few examples](http://diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/userdict.html) on doing this.

Comment: I think you should add the call to dict.__init__ from 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817884/creating-dictionaries-with-pre-defined-keys/818019#818019 (or even better, user super).

Comment: That's how I had it originally (check out the history), but after some research you apparently don't need it in this case. According to the Dive Into Python link above: "dict does not work like this; it is not a wrapper, and it requires no explicit initialization." - I'd love some more details on that, though, as it was my first instinct to have the super call in there.

Comment: It used to be the case that you couldn't subclass types using __init__ at all; you had to muck around with __new__.  Perhaps it's related to that.

Answer (score 12):

You can also have the dict subclass restrict the keys to a predefined list, by overriding `__setitem__()`

```
>>> class LimitedDict(dict):
    _keys = "a b c".split()
    def __init__(self, valtype=int):
        for key in LimitedDict._keys:
            self[key] = valtype()
    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        if key not in LimitedDict._keys:
            raise KeyError
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, val)


>>> limited = LimitedDict()
>>> limited['a']
0
>>> limited['a'] = 3
>>> limited['a']
3
>>> limited['z'] = 0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#61>", line 1, in <module>
    limited['z'] = 0
  File "<pyshell#56>", line 8, in __setitem__
    raise KeyError
KeyError
>>> len(limited)
3
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution for me, thanks! However, could you explain why do you declare '_keys' property with underscore character at the beginning?

Comment: Late response, but the leading underscore is informal notation to indicate that the member is local ("protected").

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in Python `dict` is a class , so you can subclass it:

```
    class SubDict(dict):
        def __init__(self):
            dict.__init__(self)
            self.update({
                'foo': 'bar',
                'baz': 'spam',})
```

Here you override dict's `__init__()` method (a method which is called when an instance of the class is created). Inside `__init__` you first call supercalss's `__init__()` method, which is a common practice when you whant to expand on the functionality of the base class. Then you update the new instance of `SubDictionary` with your initial data.

```
    subDict = SubDict()
    print subDict    # prints {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'spam'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but when I read your post I immediately thought you were looking to dynamically generate keys for counting exercises.

Unlike perl, which will do this for you by default,

```
grep{$_{$_}++} qw/ a a b c c c /;
print map{$_."\t".$_{$_}."\n"} sort {$_{$b}$_{$a}} keys %_;

c   3
a   2
b   1
```

Python won't give you this for free:

```
l = ["a","a","b","c","c","c"]
d = {}
for item in l:
    d[item] += 1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./y.py", line 6, in 
    d[item] += 1
KeyError: 'a'
```

however, defaultdict will do this for you,

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

l = ["a","a","b","c","c","c"]
d = defaultdict(int)
for item in l:
    d[item] += 1

dl = sorted(d.items(),key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
for item in dl:
    print item

('c', 3)
('a', 2)
('b', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a subclass of dict and add the keys in the **init** method.

```
class MyClass(dict)

def __init__(self):
    """Creates a new dict with default values""""

    self['key1'] = 'value1'
```

Remember though, that in python any class that 'acts like a dict' is usually treated like one, so you don't have to worry too much about it being a subclass, you could instead implement the dict methods, although the above approach is probably more useful to you :).